# Locate files written by a python script in a container that is not running anymore

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I have a python script that is dumping a pandas dataframe into a file using :

```py
dataframe.to_csv(file.csv)
```

After executing the docker container using:

```sh
sudo docker-compose up freqtrade # ...rest of the command
```

I can't locate the file.csv and my cwd is freqtrade/ but can't access the filesystem in the container.

Also tried to save the file to a path in the ubuntu file system but got the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/kato/freqtrade/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the container has been stopped and has not been removed you should still find it using [docker ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) with `-a`:

```sh
docker ps -a
```

If you found the container ID, you can then copy files from its filesystem without starting it using [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/):

```sh
docker cp CONTAINER_ID:absolute/path/to/file ./host/target/path
```

Another solution to avoid doing this in the future, you could run your container with a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) (a directory from your machine would be mapped to a directory inside the container):

```sh
docker run -v "$(pwd)"/relative/host_dir:/absolute/container_dir my_image
```